# Having problems using Plumber with special characters

Tags: r, urlencode, plumber

I'm using Plumber as a alternative to SharePoint API, so we hosted a static file handler

```
library(plumber)
pr() %>%
  pr_static("/assets", "folder") %>%
  pr_run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8001)
```

And the folder have two files

```
simplefile.docx
Hard to read.docx
```

When i try **"0.0.0.0/assets/simplesfile.docx"** i receive the file as intended
But for **"0.0.0.0/assets/Hard%20to%20read.docx"**  i receive

```
 {"error":["404 - Resource Not Found"]}
```

I tried many encoding ways, but i think that i missed something important

Could you guys help me?

Comment: Can you rename the file by removing the spaces

Comment: Its not possible